# No puedo crear un nuevo proyecto con vue/cli me sale este error

Tags: vue.js, npm

npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fplugin-proposal-decorators reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kenshiro/.npm/_logs/2022-02-07T16_16_35_249Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta instalada la ultima version del cli?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

a veces el problema es el ancho de banda de la red que intenta usar. intenta:

**npm cache clean --force**

**npm config rm proxy**

**npm config rm https-proxy**

**npm cache verify**

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pude resolver ,se lo agradesco @Steven Burgos